# Limit Repo.preload in a User has many User through Connection setup

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Twitter like `follower` setup where `Users` can follow each other through a `connection` model. On `user#show` I'd like to display the lastest 5 `followers` and `followees`. Not knowing how many `connections` a given `user` has I'd like to limit the `Repo.preload` to those 5 latest.

I'm struggling with the way I should use Ecto to only load the latest (most recent `inserted_at` in the `Connection` model) 5 `connections` of `followers` and `followees`. What is the cleanest and most performant way?

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user =
    Repo.get!(User, id)
    |> Repo.preload([:followers, :followees])
[...]
```

**web/models/user.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    [...]
    has_many :follower_connections, MyApp.Connection, foreign_key: :followee_id
    has_many :followers, through: [:follower_connections, :follower]

    has_many :followee_connections, MyApp.Connection, foreign_key: :follower_id
    has_many :followees, through: [:followee_connections, :followee]
[...]
```

**web/models/connection.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Connection do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "connections" do
    belongs_to :follower, MyApp.User
    belongs_to :followee, MyApp.User
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to make this work directly when preloading `:followers` or `:followees` but I found a way by interacting directly with `:follower_connections` and `:followee_connections`.

```
defmodule MyApp.Connection do
  ...
  def latest(n) do
    Ecto.Query.from(u in MyApp.Connection, order_by: [desc: :inserted_at], limit: ^n)
  end
end
```

With two users with ids `1` and `2`, and a follower/followee connection between them both ways,

```
Repo.get(User, 1) |>
Repo.preload(followee_connections: {Connection.latest(5), [:followee]},
             follower_connections: {Connection.latest(5), [:follower]})
```

runs the queries

> [debug] SELECT u0."id", u0."name", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at"
>   FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" = ?) [1] OK query=0.6ms
>
> [debug] SELECT c0."id", c0."follower_id", c0."followee_id",
>   c0."inserted_at", c0."updated_at" FROM "connections" AS c0 WHERE
>   (c0."follower_id" IN (?)) ORDER BY c0."follower_id", c0."inserted_at"
>   DESC LIMIT ? [1, 5] OK query=0.4ms
>
> [debug] SELECT u0."id", u0."name", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at"
>   FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" IN (?)) [2] OK query=0.3ms
>   queue=0.1ms
>
> [debug] SELECT c0."id", c0."follower_id", c0."followee_id",
>   c0."inserted_at", c0."updated_at" FROM "connections" AS c0 WHERE
>   (c0."followee_id" IN (?)) ORDER BY c0."followee_id", c0."inserted_at"
>   DESC LIMIT ? [1, 5] OK query=0.4ms
>
> [debug] SELECT u0."id", u0."name", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at"
>   FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" IN (?)) [2] OK query=0.4ms
>   queue=0.1ms

which look efficient to me (if the preloading needs to happen in another query; otherwise some JOINs may be faster).

The only problem is that you cannot access `:followers` or `:followees` directly on the `User`, but only through `.follower` of all `.follower_connections` and `.followee` of all `.followee_connections`.

This is the struct returned with the above query:

```
%MyApp.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>,
 followee_connections: [%MyApp.Connection{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>,
   followee: %MyApp.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>,
    followee_connections: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followee_connections is not loaded>,
    followees: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followees is not loaded>,
    follower_connections: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :follower_connections is not loaded>,
    followers: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followers is not loaded>,
    id: 2, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T12:45:26Z>, name: "B",
    updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T12:45:26Z>}, followee_id: 2,
   follower: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :follower is not loaded>,
   follower_id: 1, id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T12:46:52Z>,
   updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T12:46:52Z>}],
 followees: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followees is not loaded>,
 follower_connections: [%MyApp.Connection{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>,
   followee: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followee is not loaded>,
   followee_id: 1,
   follower: %MyApp.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>,
    followee_connections: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followee_connections is not loaded>,
    followees: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followees is not loaded>,
    follower_connections: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :follower_connections is not loaded>,
    followers: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followers is not loaded>,
    id: 2, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T12:45:26Z>, name: "B",
    updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T12:45:26Z>}, follower_id: 2, id: 2,
   inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T13:53:14Z>,
   updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T13:53:14Z>}],
 followers: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :followers is not loaded>,
 id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T11:38:27Z>, name: "A",
 updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-09T12:45:22Z>}
```